# Unable to get 4k video output on android + opencv

Tags: android, resolution

I'm trying to connect a 4k camera on a Android tv device.

My problem is that i can't seem to get 4k output from the camera onto my 4k tv screen. The highest video resolution that I am able to get is 1920x1080.

I'm using opencv for android and have tried to set the resolution in initializeCamera() inside the JavaCameraView class.

```
params.setPictureSize(highestSupportedSize.width, highestSupportedSize.height);
params.setPreviewSize(highestSupportedSize.width, highestSupportedSize.height);
```

I search for the highest common resolution between the pictureSizes and previewSizes. The problem lays in the fact that the highest preview size that I can get is 1920x1080. Which is very strange since both my screen and camera support 4k.

If I manually set the picture size to 3840x2160, I get a very large green area on the screen and the camera preview part stays 1920,1080.
If I try to manually set the preview size to 3840x2160, the app crashes.

Would really appreciate someone that knows how to get 4k video output on a JavaCameraView.

**Edit:** I now have the feeling that the issue is the Android tv I'm using (Nvidia shield tv). Which might not support 4k camera input. Still trying to fix this.

**Edit2:** For anyone facing the same issue: According to Logitech customer service, the Android tv boxes don't support anything higher than 720p at the moment. There are also no plans from logitech or nvidia to create support for this.

Answer (score 0):

You chan check my question:

[android tv box 4K activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665578/android-tv-box-4k-activity)
You can select 4k for your actviti, if available.

I think a lot of tv boxes GPU only supports 4k video, but fullHD openGL surface /activities.
Maybe JavaCameraView is video over opengl.
Can you get a real 4K resolution with others non video apps, like launcher?

I downloaded a lot of apps to display screen resolution, and I always get a 
logical fullHD resolution with a 4K@60Hz display.